# HTML pop-up over flex

Tags: html, apache-flex

How can I show an html pop-up over a Flex Web application with out changing the `wmode` of the swf file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The way that the Flash plugin and browsers interact prevents it.

See http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/155/tn_15523.html